# jsgrid getting started sample does not work

Tags: javascript, grid, jsgrid

For a project of mine I have to use jsgrid (http://js-grid.com).

To test if how to use jsgrid I wanted to do the "getting started" example (http://js-grid.com/getting-started. 
My problem, in my opinion I did everything like the example said but it didn't work in the end.

What am I missing?

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid-theme.min.css" />
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsgrid/1.5.3/jsgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var clients = [
            { "Name": "Otto Clay", "Age": 25, "Country": 1, "Address": "Ap #897-1459 Quam Avenue", "Married": false },
            { "Name": "Connor Johnston", "Age": 45, "Country": 2, "Address": "Ap #370-4647 Dis Av.", "Married": true },
            { "Name": "Lacey Hess", "Age": 29, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #365-8835 Integer St.", "Married": false },
            { "Name": "Timothy Henson", "Age": 56, "Country": 1, "Address": "911-5143 Luctus Ave", "Married": true },
            { "Name": "Ramona Benton", "Age": 32, "Country": 3, "Address": "Ap #614-689 Vehicula Street", "Married": false }
        ];
     
        var countries = [
            { Name: "", Id: 0 },
            { Name: "United States", Id: 1 },
            { Name: "Canada", Id: 2 },
            { Name: "United Kingdom", Id: 3 }
        ];
     
        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            width: "100%",
            height: "400px",
     
            inserting: true,
            editing: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
     
            data: clients,
     
            fields: [
                { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
                { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
                { name: "Address", type: "text", width: 200 },
                { name: "Country", type: "select", items: countries, valueField: "Id", textField: "Name" },
                { name: "Married", type: "checkbox", title: "Is Married", sorting: false },
                { type: "control" }
            ]
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="jsGrid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script code runs before the DOM is ready. I wrapped your script in between:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and:

```
});
```

and it ran fine with the table shown. For some explanation, see [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

jsGrid is a fantastic tool. Unfortunately, it has near zero diagnostics. Something can be wrong, like a simple typo, but there is no indication at all of what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine now! I didn't see that it was in the wrong place.